# Memory management of child dialog windows

Tags: c++, qt

I use the following code to show a `MyWindowClass` window, which is a subclass of `QDialog`:

```
//header mainwindow.h
MyWindowClass *myWindow;

//mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::on_actionButton_triggered()
{
    myWindow = new MyWindowClass(this);
    myWindow->show();
}
```

I have read on StackOverflow, that `this` manages the deletion of the object:

> the window gets deleted, when the parent `mainWindow` gets deleted.

When I open the Windows Task Manager and look at the amount of RAM my program is using, the used memory is increased each time a new dialog window is open.

So far so good. However, when I close a dialog window (not the `mainWindow`), the used RAM decreases, which means that the memory gets deallocated by Qt.

As in the citation, I expect the dialog windows to be deleted once the parent `mainWindow` is deleted.

Did I get that wrong?

Comment: No need to ask: set a breakpoint in the destructor of the child objects (the dialogs), or have debug output there. You can also use `std::unique_ptr` or `QScopedPointer` to ensure deletion – you’re free to manage object lifetime yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt has a feature called parent-child relationship wherein the object you created using "this" pointer is the child and the object pointed by "this" pointer is the parent. Basically it says whenever the parent object gets deleted the object gets deleted. So in your case when the parent object was deleted, all the child objected were also deleted. This mechanism only guarantees that child object's will be deleted IF AND ONLY IF parent is deleted. If you had thought that Qt deletes the child object when your dialog box was closed, then you are wrong. Its better to use smart pointers if your concerned about memory as qt releases memory only if parent is deleted.

Comment: But how is the decreasing of the used RAM, after closing the QDialog window to explain?

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the QDialog box's that you had opened? Because I reproduced the same thing on my pc, and mine is deallocated only if the mainwindow is closed. Also try to run the exe file outside of Qt Creator environment, in a folder containing all the dll required and check the result

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have the following line in the constructor of your subclass of `QDialog`:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

This makes possible the automatic deletion of the child dialog `MyWindowClass`, when it is closed, with the parent window `MainWindow` still being open.

The documentation of [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) states:

> Makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close event (see QWidget::closeEvent()).

The following example I have prepared for you demonstrates the effect:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDialog>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
//  Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        auto *button = new QPushButton(tr("Open dialog"), this);

        setCentralWidget(button);

        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
            auto *dialog = new QDialog(this);

            dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
            dialog->resize(300, 200);
            dialog->show();

            connect(dialog, &QDialog::destroyed, [](){
                qDebug("Dialog's gone.");
            });
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This code allows a new empty dialog to be open each time a button is pressed. If a dialog window is closed, `Dialog's gone.` is printed in the console.

Commenting the line

```
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

in the example prevents the automatic deletion of dialog window objects, so no message will be printed when a dialog window is closed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, I always felt the need to delete the object in destructor when there was a big tree of children's and I could not wait for the parent to be deleted.

Comment: @Gurushant, yes, an object should live as long as it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. It is being handled by the QObject object, which is being inherited in QDialog (over QWidget).

You are passing the pointer to the parent QObject when you are using `this` and the parent takes care of the memory deallocation for all the children when the parent is being destroyed (in this case when closing the program).